# Monitor.Exit throws SynchronizationLockException

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, thread-safety, monitor

So, I have been getting this error for a bit now and I performed a few tests, but I cannot figure out the problem. I get a System.Threading.SynchronizationException when calling Monitor.Exit(). First, I created a wrapper for all Monitor methods I use that prints "Locked" and "Unlocked" to the screen. This prints out fine and right before my call to Exit, it says the lock is LOCKED. When I call exit it throws the error and FAILS to unlock my object. This is obvious and visible from my UI. It says something about can't execute from a non-synchronous block?

Note: My Monitor.Exit command is called in a different method call then my Monitor.Enter command. It is still safe, but could this be the issue?

EDIT: Background Info: I am implementing a Mario like game. When Mario goes into Transition my group wants all of our various Timers to stop updating (block their threads) and just do a specific update to our player. All the Timer threads already have a common lock being used called TimerLock. Here is the sample code for this transition.

```
    public void Begin()
    {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(ManagedTimer.Lock,100))
        {

            try
            {
                //Turn off updating for all objects
                TurnOffPhysicsUpdate(); //Psuedocode for this...

                //Create timer till end event
                EndTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(600.00);
                EndTimer.AutoReset = false;
                EndTimer.Elapsed += EndTimer_Elapsed;
                EndTimer.Enabled = true;
                EndTimer.Start();

                //Create swap timer
                SwapTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(25.0);
                SwapTimer.AutoReset = false;
                SwapTimer.Elapsed += SwapTimer_Elapsed;
                SwapTimer.Enabled = true;
                SwapTimer.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                EndFreeze();
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to setup transition: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void SwapTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
            SwapTimer.Stop();
            //Transition Mario State....
            SwapTimer.Start();
    }

    private void EndTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        EndFreeze();
    }

    private void EndFreeze()
    {
        try
        {
            SwapTimer.Stop();
            EndTimer.Stop();

            TurnOnPhysicsUpdate(); //psuedocode

            //Ensure Mario ends in the proper state
            user.StateMachine.TransitionSizeState(newState);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("FATAL ERROR: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Exception occurs here!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            Monitor.Exit(ManagedTimer.Lock,"TimerLock");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like your enter and exit calls are out of sync, if you'll excuse the pun.

Comment: Are you on the right thread when exiting? it must exit from the same thread that entered

Comment: When you say out of sync what do you mean? I know the object is locked at the time of my call. All I can figure is that it's the fact that they weren't called from the same method...

Comment: The question is very ambiguous. Showing some sample code might help. The obvious question that comes to mind is, "What condition in your code are you really trying to solve?"  -- Additional info, like, is this a Windows Forms app? Would be helpful for us to understand the problem better.

Comment: The transitions work properly, but when its exiting, the Monitor.Exit throws an exception and doesn't release...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `EndTimer_Elapsed` method is called by the timer, you are not in the same thread that owns the lock, so you are not permitted to release the lock there.

This is a good example of why one should just avoid using `Monitor.Enter/Exit` altogether. It's pretty tricky for even an expert in concurrent programming to get everything just right, and it's a minefield for anyone else. If you stick with using Monitor via the `lock` statement, it becomes a lot harder to make this kind of mistake. :)

Finally note that it's not really clear from your example *why* you are using this lock. You might consider posting a different question explaining the synchronization issue you're trying to solve, so that you can get help designing the code correctly and without `Monitor.Enter/Exit`

Comment: Thanks for the help. my timer thread calls the Exit and my main thread calls the Enter. That makes sense, but I'm not really sure how to solve this without causing massive rifts in the codebase... I can't post for another hour and a half... so if you have any tips I'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: I'm sure I and others can offer suggestions, but not without more information about why you are taking this lock in the first place. Keeping a lock for such a long duration is unusual and probably ill-advised here. (I know 25, and even 600 ms seems like a short timer, but for a modern computer it's an eternity)

Comment: Ok, well I can go into more detail it just hard to summarize a project in a short blurb. We have Mario and the goal is those Mario transitions. Sprites and a few other components (for decoupling) know how to activate and update themselves via timers. We are all in school and haven't done much with threading, so we decided to put one lock around all timers to ensure no two threads ran over each other. (The speed loss for a game like this didn't seem to have any effect). Now to transition, the easiest way to stop all those timers seemed to be having the transition method take the lock.

Comment: I know it can be hard to summarize. That's why a) this type of forum is not best for larger design-related questions, and b) if you do want help with those kinds of questions, you need to distill the important elements down into a concise-but-complete code example that reliably demonstrates the problem (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So I created the code above to take the lock, perform several state swaps back and forth and eventually after a larger amount of time release the lock allowing all the items to continue. I know this wastes the advantages of multithreading, but we didn't know the timers functioned with multithreading until way later sadly. *face palm*

Comment: This is why I asked you to tell us what problem you are trying to solve. I could have posted some helpful code that allows you to update UI elements from other threads asynchronously. Updating UI elements from external threads is a fairly common task.